# XDebug in AMPPS and Atom

Tags: php, xdebug, ampps

How do I setup XDebug in AMPPS and Atom? I spent 4 hours, still unable to make it work. I want to use PHP 7.1, so on ampps, i changed php version to 7.1 and installed xdebug with

```
brew install php71-xdebug
```

added the following config in application/AMPPS/php-7.1/etc/php.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1    # Not safe for production servers
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so"
```

Used the following code

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

I don't see xdebug in the output. I put debug breakpoint in the second line in atom, but not working.

When I ran Run `php -i "(command-line 'phpinfo()')"`
 got the following error

Failed loading /usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
-bash: Run: command not found

log has the following 
Failed loading /usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: Try to move zend_extension to before of [xdebug] and restart server.

Comment: @Vuong Tried not working